# MS SQL Server Licenses

Tags: sql-server, license, licensing, volume-license

I was having a discussion at work about the licensing model of Microsoft, in particular for SQL Server and we couldn't agree on the interpretation of "Active SA Quantity".

So the question is, if for SQL Server Ent. Lic. I have 10 Active SA Quantity, does that mean that we are covered for 20 cores on the server? (since licenses come in packs of 2)? What do you think?

Thanks!

Comment: I would reach out to the reseller you purchased these from and have them help you figure it out so you know 100% for sure rather than debating who is right. I though SQL Enterprise was only core based licensed (depending on when you first purchased the licenses) and those were 4 core minimum but I wouldn't guess on the licensing and if you don't understand then get with a licensing profession to get clarity on the topic and start with the reseller you originally purchased the licenses and SA to start and then you will know who it right colleague wise.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server licenses (both for initial purchase & ongoing Software Assurance) are licensed by the CPU core. However, licenses are sold in 2-core packs. Every SKU that you see on an invoice from Microsoft will be for 2-core license packs.

Context becomes very important. Often times people conflate "licensed CPU cores" and "licenses for CPU cores". It is generally easiest to **always** talk in terms of CPU cores *or* licenses, rather than going back & forth. Thankfully, the Microsoft Sales team always talks in terms of licenses, and not cores.

Therefore, if you are seeing an invoice, quote, or other official number from Microsoft, which shows "10 Active SA" this most likely means "10 SA licenses" or "20 CPU cores covered by SA."